# Box constraints not respecting minWidth and minHeight

Tags: flutter, dart

My container width and height size defaults to the minWidth and maxWidth property set in the BoxConstraints which is contrary to the result I want. It should grow from the minWidth then hit the maxWdith and stop growing. Code below.

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: reapeatedReply == false ? 10 : 0),
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 10,
            vertical: 5,
          ),
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: reapeatedReply == true ? 12 : 0, bottom: 3),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, bottom: 3),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: deviceSize.width * 0.8,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFFFF5C7),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: reapeatedReply == true
                    ? Radius.circular(10)
                    : Radius.zero),
          ),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  text,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .body1
                      .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    child: Text(
                      "8:45 PM",
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .body1
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `minWidth` is only applied when the child widget is smaller or equal with the defined minimum width. On the other hand, `maxWidth` is achieved when the child widget's dimension is larger or equal with the defined max width.